# How to refresh a html page without using a html form? Tried redirect: it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to delete a question. By using following endpoint I can delete a question without any issue. But I need to refresh the forum.html page after deleting the question. I used "redirect:/forum.html" but it does not work.How can I refresh the forum.html

```
@Controller
public class ForumController {

 @PostMapping("/deleteQuestion")
    public String deleteQuestion(@RequestParam Long questionId){


        questionRepository.deleteById(questionId);


        return "redirect:/forum.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript native function to reload your page:

```js
window.location.reload(true)
```

You can use this function when your deleting request is completed as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery function for reload

```
location.reload(true);
```

or

```
location.replace(location.pathname);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).